# Is it possible to run multiple QOpenGLWidgets with one fullscreen on another screen?

Tags: opengl, qt5, fullscreen

On screen 0, I have the `mainWindow` with two `QOpenGLWidgets` running video. On screen 1, I have another `QOpenGLWidget` in fullscreen mode running video. The screen 0 is a preview of what the user is seeing on the second display, which is a pair of glasses. Everything was working fine, until I added the fullscreen widget. Now only the fullscreen widget updates and the other two only update if I cause the window to repaint, e.g. moving the window.

I am a noob when it comes to *opengl*, but the two widgets, in the `mainWindow` are running together fine. So I don't believe it is the code. Is this a limitation of opengl? Qt? me?

I am using Qt5.4.

Answer (score 0):

I missed an error in the console due to a lot of noise.

```
Requires a valid current OpenGL context.

Texture has not been destroyed
```

A quick search and I got my answer. I wasn't calling makeCurrent() when I was updating the texture with the next frame.